# How can I reach End Of File?

Tags: java, indexing, location, eof

I am designing a program that saves the index location for specific characters from a message. Then, I need to retrieve these characters according to their index location. I kept the locations for these characters in a .txt file. I retrieved them, but at the end, I got this message "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 120 out of bounds for length 120".
My codes:

```
int n;
String s; 
int lineNumCount = 0;
String coverText = stegoMsg.getText(); // get the stego text from the textfield
int k = coverText.length(); // get the length for the stego text
int lineNumb = 1;
Scanner myFile = null;
          try{
               Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("location.txt"));//location.txt is the file that has the locations for the characters
               myFile = file;
             }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                 System.out.println("File does not found");
             }
        while (myFile.hasNextLine()){
            //Count the Number of the lines in location.txt
            //1. Read the File
            File fileLocation = new File("location.txt"); 
            if(fileLocation.exists()){
                try {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileLocation);
                    LineNumberReader lr = new LineNumberReader(fr); //2. Read the lines for location.txt
                    
                    while((lr.readLine()) !=null){
                    lineNumCount++;
                            }
                   // System.out.println("Total Number of the Lines " + lineNumCount);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ExtPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ExtPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            
           for(int x = 0; x<lineNumCount; ++x){
            try{
                String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("location.txt")).get(lineNumb);
               // System.out.println("Line First " + line);
                BufferedReader bufrd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SFile.txt")); //SFile.txt is the file that has the messsage that I need to take the location for the specific characters
                int nn = Integer.parseInt(line);  
                s = bufrd.readLine();
                System.out.println("The Location " + nn  + " is : "+ s.charAt(nn)); // read the character that has this location
                lineNumb++;
                
                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Line 334");
                }
           }
            }
        }
        myFile.close();
 }
```

Is it possible to guide me on how I can solve the exception?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The code seems very confused. You seem to be treating the same file (location.txt) several times. If you need to count the number of lines in it (I'm not convinced you do), you should be calling `hasNextLine` on the `Scanner` and counting them. Could you please describe, in simple words, what exactly you are doing?

Comment: I edited my codes .. I was calling `hasNextLine` so by mistake I called `hasNext`. So What I am doing is: I saved the index for some characters in (location.txt) file, these characters are taken from a message found in SFile.txt.. then here in these codes I want to retrieve the characters from SFile.txt that have the locations saved in location.txt. ... Hope I could transfer my idea

Comment: Personally I would put SFile.txt into a `List<String>` then you can access the file randomly with the right location. As far as the locations are concerned, I would save the locations as lines of `<line number><space><line offset>`

Comment: lineNumb is initialized to 1 and then incremented. Remember that Java uses zero based indexing.

Comment: @Christopher right.. But I don't have any problem with retrieving.. I just had the error that tells (Index 120 out of bounds for length 120).

Comment: @Asst.Farah - Christopher's last comment tells you the reason that you are getting that `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution ...

```
        int n;
        String s; 
        int lineNumCount = 0;
        String coverText = stegoMsg.getText(); // get the stego text from the textfield
        int k = coverText.length(); // get the length for the stego text
        int lineNumb = 1;
        Scanner myFile = null;
        try{
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("location.txt"));
        myFile = file;
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File does not found");
        }
       try{
        while (myFile.hasNext()){
            //Count the Number of the lines in location.txt
            //1. Read the File
            File fileLocation = new File("C:\\Users\\Farah\\Dropbox\\Steganography codes\\NewStegoTech\\location.txt");
            if(fileLocation.exists()){
                try {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileLocation);
                    LineNumberReader lr = new LineNumberReader(fr); //2. Read the lines for location.txt
                    
                    while((lr.readLine()) !=null){
                    lineNumCount++;
                            }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ExtPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ExtPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            
          try{
                String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("location.txt")).get(lineNumb);
               // System.out.println("Line First " + line);
                BufferedReader bufrd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Stego File.txt"));
                int nn = Integer.parseInt(line);  
                s = bufrd.readLine();
                System.out.println("The Loocation " + nn  + " is : "+ s.charAt(nn)); // read the character that has this location
                lineNumb++;
                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
           
            }
        }
       }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
       {
           System.out.println("Finish reading file");
       }
       
        myFile.close();
```